# Python tuple ... is not a tuple? What does the comma do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I was looking at code in my course material and had to write a function which adds the value 99 to either a `list` or `tuple`. The final code looks like this:

```
def f(l):
    print(l)
    l += 99,
    print(l)

f([1,2,3])
f((1,2,3))
```

This was used to show something different but I'm getting somewhat hung up on the line `l += 99,`. What this does, is create an iterable that contains the 99 and `list` as well as `tuple` support the simple "addition" of such an object to create a new instance/add a new element.

What I don't really get is what exactly is created using the syntax `element,`? If I do an assignment like `x = 99,` the `type(x)` will be `tuple` but if I try run `x = tuple(99)` it will fail as the 99 is not iterable. So is there:

- Some kind of intermediate iterable object created using the syntax `element,`?
- Is there a special function defined that would allow the calling of `tuple` without an iterable and somehow `,` is mapped to that?

Edit:
In case anyone wonders why the accepted answer is the one it is: The explanation for my second question made it. I should've been more clear with my question but that `+=` is what actuallly got me confused and this answer includes information on this.

Comment: @ScottHunter `x = 99,`, not `x = 99;` comma vs semi-colon

Comment: This question has actually uncovered something I was not aware of before. Apparently the `list.__add__` method (for addition) will not accept a `tuple` for the `other` argument, but `list.__iadd__` (for +=) does accept it. I wonder why that is?

Comment: That smells like a bug @RickTeachey

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard seems that way to me too, but I tend to take Treebeard's advice and not be too hasty.

Comment: @RickTeachey I'll see if I can find anything on the bug tracker and/or source, this has me pretty surprised too. Edit: [Found it](https://bugs.python.org/issue12318) :-)

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard "It's been that way for a long while and Guido said he wouldn't do it again (it's in his list of regrets).  However, we're not going to break code by changing it (list.__iadd__ working like list.extend)." COWARDS! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `element,` simply creates an "intermediate" `tuple`, not some other kind of object (though a `tuple` is of course iterable).

However, sometimes you need to use parentheses in order to avoid ambiguity. For this reason, you'll often see this:

```
l += (99,)
```

...even though the parentheses are not syntactically necessary. I also happen to think that is easier to read. But the parentheses ARE syntactically necessary in other situations, which you have already discovered:

```
list((99,))
tuple((99,))
set((99,))
```

You can also do these, since `[]` makes a `list`:

```
list([99])
tuple([99])
set([99])
```

...but you can't do these, since `99,` is not a `tuple` object in these situations:

```
list(99,)
tuple(99,)
set(99,)
```

To answer your second question, no, there is not a way to make the `tuple()` function receive a non-iterable. In fact this is the purpose of the `element,` or `(element,)` syntax - very similar to `[]` for `list` and `{}` for `dict` and `set` (since the `list`, `dict`, and `set` functions all also require iterable arguments):

```
[99] #list 
(99,) #tuple -  note the comma is required
{99} #set
```

As discussed in the question comments, it surprising that you can increment (+=) a `list` using a `tuple` object. Note that you cannot do this:

```
l = [1]  
l + (2,) # error
```

This is inconsistent, so it is [probably something that should not have been allowed](https://bugs.python.org/issue12318). Instead, you would need to do one of these:

```
l += [2]
l += list((2,))
```

However, fixing it would create problems for people (not to mention remove a ripe opportunity for confusion exploitation by evil computer science professors), so they didn't.

Answer (score 5):

If the left-hand argument of `=` is a simple name, the type of argument *currently* bound to that name is irrelevant. `tuple(99)` fails because `tuple`'s argument is not iterable; it has nothing to do with whether or not `x` already refers to an instance of `tuple`.

`99,` creates a tuple with a single argument; parentheses are only necessary to separate it from other uses of commas. For example, `foo((99,100))` calls `foo` with a single tuple argument, while `foo(99,100)` calls `foo` with two distinct `int` arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The tuple constructor requires an iterable (like it says in your error message) so in order to do `x = tuple(99)`, you need to include it in an iterable like a list:

```
x = tuple([99])
```

or

```
x = tuple((99,))
```