# Why does variable value separated by ',' shows datatype as Tuple

Tags: python

This was a code I stumbled upon to:

```
tuple1 = 10, 20
tuple2 = (10, 20)

print(type(tuple1))
print(type(tuple2))
```

Comment: Because ``,`` defines a tuple.

Comment: This will do it too: `t = 10,`

Comment: If you assign multiple values to a variable like that then they are stored in a tuple. Similarly, if you return multiple values separated with a comma then they are returned in a tuple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python tuple … is not a tuple? What does the comma do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067409/python-tuple-is-not-a-tuple-what-does-the-comma-do)

Comment: The comma defines a tuple, not the parentheses.

Comment: This question was wrongly closed as a duplicate.  The supposed "duplicate" specifically concerns expressions with trailing commas.  This question is asking about the general syntax for tuples with/without parentheses. To a new programmer it would not be obvious that these are special cases of the same syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use comma-separated expressions on the right-hand side of an assignment, this is called “tuple packing”. It creates a tuple; parentheses are not required for this:

```
tuple1 = 10, 20
```

Similarly, if you give comma-separated names on the **left**-hand side of an assignment, “tuple **un**packing” is performed:

```
int1, int2 = tuple1
```

This is how multiple assignment works – It’s actually tuple packing combined with tuple unpacking:

```
int1, int2 = 10, 20
```

You can use this to swap the values of two variables without having to use a temporary variable:

```
int1, int2 = int2, int1
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how the [syntax for tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) works.  The parentheses are optional when creating a tuple.

> ... on output tuples are always enclosed in parentheses, so that nested tuples are interpreted correctly; **they may be input with or without surrounding parentheses**, although often parentheses are necessary anyway (if the tuple is part of a larger expression).

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#when-to-use-trailing-commas

Comment: @DorianTurba The OP didn't ask about trailing commas...